# Get last executed query with PHP native

Tags: php, postgresql

My code is like this:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT a, b, c FROM `tb_mysql`');

$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=db_postgresql user=postgres password=1234") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

$sql = array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $sql[] = '(\''.$r['a'].'\',\''.$r['b'].'\',\''.$r['c'].'\')';
}

$q = pg_exec($dbconn, "INSERT INTO tb_postgresql(a, b, c) VALUES ".implode(',', $sql));
```

I want to `echo last query insert`

How to get last executed query with PHP native?

Comment: You want mysql or postgresql?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk, potgresql

Comment: `pg_exec` is not a PHP method

Comment: Have you got a MySQL and Postgresql database in this app?

Comment: @worldofjr, I take the data from mysql database and the data I input to the database postgresql. I am confused how to `echo last query` in normal php

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I have tested in my local its working fine

Comment: In codeigniter use : `echo $this->db->last_query();`. In php native?